# Updating Elasticsearch Document and ignoring specific field using ElasticSearch Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm using ElasticSearch Spring Data to manage documents in my application, and I'm facing a situation where I need to update a document without affecting a particular large object within it. I don't want to load this large object while retrieving the document. Unfortunately, when I update other fields in the document and save it again, the large object gets removed, as it was not loaded initially.

Is there a recommended approach to achieve this while using ElasticSearch Spring Data?

**Example:**

Let's assume I have a document representing a user profile. This document includes fields like username, email, and a complex "preferences" object which I don't want to load when querying the user profile. However, when I update the username and email fields and save the document using the save method in the spring data repo, the "preferences" object gets cleared, even though I never loaded it in the first place.